# I have a postdoc interview tomorrow and I think I have overstated my abilities in my CV. How do I address it during the interview?

Tags: postdocs, interview

I received a postdoc interview invitation at a prestigious group under a reputed PI. The professor works in a loosely related field "X" and is looking for people with expertise in the field. I have just started to work on "X" (since March 2021) and am planning to do more dedicated work on the "X" in the next 6 months.

In my cover letter, among other things, I wrote that I have been working on "X" topic as part of my PhD thesis.

Now, I am sure I received the call due the mention of "X" in my CV. However, it is evident that I don't know much about "X" and will be asked about it in detail.

Now, I am scared for the interview. They might make a mockery out of me. Is there a way to address this before the interview?

Comment: Only if you want them to reject you out of hand! Suppress your doubts, and do the best you can. If the topic comes up, just tell them the truth: you did some work on it, but not enough to make you an expert.

Comment: What might be the case is that the professor is interested in questions relating X to whatever topic your thesis is on. Keep an open mind. Good luck!

Comment: If you didn't make any previous explicit statements about your knowledge of X that are more than what you actually know about X, and if you're forced to confront the fact that you know less about X than they expected, then maybe try to convey the idea that, while X came up during your PhD work, you are very interested in X and would like to learn more about X, and you were hoping that the postdoc would allow you the opportunity to learn more about X.

Comment: Well @compmatsci, how did it go?

Comment: A way to seem like you know something is to ask intelligent questions about X before they get around to asking you any X questions.  Read some papers, find out some interesting edge cases.  Ask about them.  And, as others have pointed out, be honest about the limits of your knowledge (but only when pressed) and don't undersell yourself.  This is from years of non-academic (industry) interviews.  Whatever you do, don't make stuff up.

Comment: "They might make a mockery out of me" This sentence is an insecure thinking pattern. If you ever recognize one of these in your head you should acknowledge it and replace with a rational thought. "Are they going to mock me? Of course not!They are rational adults and only want people for their postdoc position. They are not out to get you". If you become good at this you will have less worries in your life.

Comment: @compmatsci  Well - how **did** it go ?

Answer (score 82):

It doesn't sound like you overstated anything. You mentioned relevant experience in a topic that you are currently working on as part of your thesis. You never claimed to be an expert, nor did you state specific experience that you can't justify.

You're worried that a reader might misinterpret that, but it doesn't sound like you've done anything to deliberately mislead anyone. Most likely, one of their first questions about your work will be to elaborate on your work in topic X. This will give you a chance to give a detailed answer.

The most important thing in an interview is to be upfront. **Do not downplay your work**. But also, don't pretend to know more than you do. Give a straightforward and direct explanation of what you did - don't editorialize based on what you/they might think your experience "should" be.

e.g. "I worked on topic X to support my research into Y. Through this work, I gained some experience with methods 1, 2 and 3. I began working on this specific topic last March and would love to pursue it further in my postdoctoral research."

Comment: +1 for emphasizing **both** "do not pretend" and "do not downplay". As part of this, contrary to another answer, do not dread questions about X.

Comment: Huge (+1) for the comment "don't editorialize".  Some of the most appalling talks I have had the "joy" of sitting through involve a lot of editorializing about how lovely a particular theorem is, how clever someone was for proving a proposition, or how earth-shatteringly important some result is.  In the words of Joe Friday, "Just the facts, ma'am."

Answer (score 19):

Remember:

- If you have non-zero experience in X, then stating you have experience in X is not overstating.
- Do not be scared, and consider the [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome).
  If the skill is rare, maybe you're the only candidate with experience in X at all.  In my experience, junior researchers often not only underestimate their skills, but also underestimate how rare certain fields of experience are.  That won't work if X is "programming Python", but it might work if X is "sudden dimming of young stars" or "satellite data rescue".

Motivation is important:

- **Do** use your short experience in X to convince them you enjoy doing X.  Even if a short experience may not be enough to jump into a topic for with in-depth experience would be preferred, it's probably enough to convince the panel that you find it interesting and are motivated to learn more.
- **Don't** say you want to study X because you can't find a job in your own field.

Answer (score 14):

What you should consider is that almost everyone is guilty of overstating their skills and experiences in their job applications or CVs, especially in highly competitive fields. And prospective employers are probably aware of that, too.

Telling them that you have less experience than they think you might have doesn't shed the best light on you, though. The best course of action would be to try to be as confident as possible in your interview and to highlight your other achievements (after all, they might have just as well invited you to the interview not only or not because you claim to have experience in X, but because of other things you bring to the table). When the dreaded subject X comes up, tell them that you do indeed have first experiences in that area (which is not wrong if you are already looking into it at the moment), and that you are currently broadening your knowledge on that topic. Showing initiative and willingness to learn might be just as well received as you already having a larger knowledge on the topic.

It might be that they reject you because they really do need someone with a strong working knowledge of X, but better than to not have gone to the interview at all.

Answer (score 12):

> They might make a mockery out of me.

Good employers are polite to people they choose not to hire.  They know that being rude will hurt their reputation.

> Is there a way to address this before the interview?

No.  Read their publications; but you should be doing that anyway.

You could decline the interview, but I suggest that you only do that if you do not want the job.

Answer (score 11):

I was in the position of your prof, only in an industrial context (which does not change much). I really wanted to get someone who would work on "X".

Out of the people who said they had experience with "X" (while in reality they only had a vague idea about it), two stood out:

- one who was actually very knowledgeable
- one who clearly showed that they were not very knowledgeable but they were really, **really** interested in the topic and wanted to learn and improve quickly.

I hired both. They still work with me and everyone is happy. You should really aim for the latter case.

Comment: You and they were lucky you were in a position to hire both!

Comment: As a new grad, I was the latter and ended up getting hired even though (imo) I completely bombed the interview.